# How expensive is it to resort a sorted collection by adding it to a SortedSet

Tags: java, sorting

This is more of a curiosity, as I've never noticed a performance issue. Presume set size between 1-1000. Here's one case:

```
private static SortedSet<GrantedAuthority> sortAuthorities(
    final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities ) {
    return authorities.stream()
        .filter( Objects::nonNull )
        .sorted( Comparator.nullsFirst( Comparator.comparing( GrantedAuthority::getAuthority ) ) )
        .collect( Collectors.toCollection( TreeSet::new ) );
}
```

but the more common case I run into would be getting an ordered list back from a "SQL query" that's already sorted, and then wanting to put it into `SortedSet`. Obviously this is premature optimization if I've never noticed a problem, I'm just curious as to what kind of overhead this causes on a micro level (note: usually I use a `TreeSet` for this).

Comment: Why are you bothering with sorting at all if you're putting the elements into a `TreeSet`?

Comment: @Makoto in the case of SQL if you are limiting the amount you get back you have to use the database to order it.

Comment: That raises even *more* questions; if you're pulling back elements from your datastore, then why are you bothering *at all* to sort or order it?  Your datastore should be responsible for the order you pull elements back in, at which point, a `List` would suffice.

Comment: @Makoto because `Set` interface, and auto sorting/unique if you add more elements to it after the load (for whatever reason).

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want to do this kind of thing in Java unless you *absolutely* had to.  From what I'm seeing, you're placing elements into a sorted collection without any real pretense to do so, which complicates the nature of the query of elements you're pulling back *and* muddles the query's correctness; for example, if your query *did* somehow bring back two duplicate records, you'd want to know about that to check if it's a query issue or a data issue.

Comment: I've also run into weird code in our code base where it needed a set, but we needed it to retain order... we could argue all day about whether or not that code is well designed.

Comment: @Makoto so you don't think a Set is the right abstract for SQL which is based on Set's....

Comment: @Makoto also instead of arguing about my curiousity, maybe you could consider answering the question?

Comment: +1 to using `select distinct ... order by ...` + a non-sorting collection instead. If you feed a `TreeSet` with an already sorted input stream, the tree will have to be re-balanced pretty often, nearly at every insert. Should not be noticeable on the background of doing I/O for DB interaction, though.

Comment: I'm trying to determine if it's answerable.  Your pretense doesn't make any practical sense, so I don't know why would one want to do this.

Comment: @Makoto I unfortunately work for a company where the code is not always perfect, so sometimes things come up and it's easier to choose the more readable solution than the more optimized one that no one can follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add n items to a `TreeSet`, you cannot assume the time complexity better than O(n*log<sub>2</sub>n), even if the items are ordered. An even larger overhead comes from the constant factor, through, because the collection needs to allocate n tree nodes to accommodate your data.

If your collection comes pre-sorted, you will be better off storing it in a plain list, assuming that you do not need to modify the results. Binary search on a sorted list os O(log<sub>2</sub>n), while there's virtually no overhead in storing it on read. The only benefit of reading into a `TreeSet` is the possibility of O(log<sub>2</sub>n) insertions and deletions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `Set`, and it needs to be ordered, then you correctly identified `TreeSet` as the appropriate set.

However, you seem to try to sort the data first, in an order that is apparently different from the *natural* order of the objects in question. The standard `TreeSet` constructor will order the set according to the *natural* order, so that will totally ignore any sorting done before adding the items to the set.

To get the set ordered as you seem to want, you need to give that `Comparator` to the `TreeSet` instead:

```
return authorities.stream()
    .filter( Objects::nonNull )
    .collect( Collectors.toCollection( () ->
                 new TreeSet( Comparator.nullsFirst(
                    Comparator.comparing( GrantedAuthority::getAuthority ) ) ) ) );
```

Of course, you should remember that a set cannot have duplicate entries, so if multiple entries can have the same `Authority` string, you'd need to add a secondary comparison, e.g. using [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-).