# What is the most efficient method for creating a large SortedSet (Java) from smaller pre-sorted collections?

Tags: java, sorting, set, treeset

I am constructing a Set of >200,000,000 objects, that needs to be ordered by one of the object attributes. At this moment, the set is converted to a list, which is then sorted. Naturally, this operation takes a while, and I hope to optimise this part of my code. I understand that, if the objects are added in unknown order, this is probably the most efficient method (see e.g. [Is it faster to sort a list after inserting items or adding them to a sorted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168891/is-it-faster-to-sort-a-list-after-inserting-items-or-adding-them-to-a-sorted-lis)).

However, the objects are added by sets of on average 1000-5000 objects, which I know are sorted. Is there a way to use this information during set construction, and minimise the sorting time for this problem? I provide an example using TreeSet, but as far as I could find (e.g. [How expensive is it to resort a sorted collection by adding it to a SortedSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316698/how-expensive-is-it-to-resort-a-sorted-collection-by-adding-it-to-a-sortedset)) adding implicitly ordered sets to a TreeSet does not reduce sorting time.

```
SortedSet<Transition> sortedTransitionSet = 
              new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(k -> k.getTimeSeconds()));
for (Segment segment: segments) {
    Set<Transition> segmentTransitions = segment.getTransitions();
    sortedTransitionSet.addAll(segmentTransitions);
}
```

Classes Segment and Transition are my own. A Transition object contains a field containing a time stamp in seconds, by which the resulting TreeSet needs to be ordered.

Comment: Do you really need 200M objects in their exact sorted order? Could you get away with bucketing them?

Comment: TreeSet is going to be very slow because of all the tree branch nodes, and the indirection of accessing all these objects. I would have thought that some sort of merge sort between two array(/list)s would be substantially faster.

Comment: I wish I could, but no. In the next step, I iterate through all of them, and every iteration builds on the result of the previous one. I know I should find a better way, but restructuring the entire pipeline is a whole new project. Sorting isn't _that_ bad as its batch processing anyway, but If it's possible I'd like to optimise this step.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm not a computer scientist, but I've of course looked into merge sort for this problem. Is there an 'easy' or 'proven' approach for this type of problem, or would I have to design it myself?

Comment: what if you drop 1, 10, 10k etc items from the data - is it really so brittle that you would get meaningfully different results?

Comment: Nah, if I have to be honest, probably not. Bucketing them per, say, 100,000 objects will not significantly change results, but will decrease computation cost. It is probably the way to go. Yet, it feels like giving in, and would love to know if there is any way to improve on the original problem.

Comment: Do you need to sort them before the final addition to the list?  The built-in algorithms for sorting a `List` are _particularly_ good at sorting with pre-sorted chunks.

Comment: If  all the small groups are pre-sorted, then what you need is a merge operation, not a sort, or perhaps a variation of TimSort that will take advantage of having 1000 to 5000 object groups presorted.